# How to take sreenshots on Nexus 4 running Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screenshot, nexus-4

I've just flashed Ubuntu Touch & Android dual-boot onto my Nexus 4. It's awesome with a mobile device running two OSes at the same time.

I want to know that how can I take screenshots on Ubuntu Touch running on Nexus 4?

Comment: Concerning taking sreenshots, i think the best method is using the light or proximity sensor.First you open the screenshot app and leave it running as a daemon. then you use one hand or finger cover the sensors whenever you want,and the other hand or finger moves on the screen and stays wherever you like.Thus you can easily capture the subtle actions such as switching between app, or dragging to unlock the phone.     This is how it works on Nokia N9 running MeeGo.

Answer (score 1):

Using the devel channel for mako (nexus 4) if you hold down both the volume buttons together it takes a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For Mir:

phablet-screenshot from phablet-tools package.
or
mirfbdump (a bash script, orginally not support Nexus 5)

perhaps can help you. but to me, all fails. sad..... I use Nexus 5.